# Sticky Footer and Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer, sticky

I found this jsfiddle here at stackoverflow, but the solution provided by the person is very jumpy. http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ZVzEe/ I need something very smooth.

```
var secondary = $("#secondary-footer");

secondary.hide().addClass("fixed").fadeIn("fast");

$(window).scroll(function() {
if (secondary.offset().top >= ($(document).height() - 350)) {
    secondary.removeClass("fixed");
}
else if(secondary + ":not('.fixed')") {
    secondary.addClass("fixed");
}
});
```

How I need the sticky footer to work is for it to show the footer as a narrow bar at the bottom of the page while still scrolling through the content. Once the bottom of the page is reached with the scrollbar, the footer will expand in height.

The jsfiddle provided is very close to how I need this to work, but I need something very smooth. And another note, the height of the fully expanded footer is not fixed. Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/bWyF4/)

**jQuery**

```
var secondary = $("#secondary-footer");

secondary.hide().addClass("fixed").fadeIn("fast");

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    $("#content").css("bottom",secondary.height());

    var maxHeight = 350; // set maximum height of the footer here
    var minHeight = 120; // set the minimum height of the footer here

    secondary.height(maxHeight - ($(document).height() - scrollBottom));
    if (secondary.height() <= minHeight) secondary.height(minHeight);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #dedede;
    position:relative; /* added this */
}
#secondary-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #666;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* removed #secondary-footer.fixed  and merged content with #secondary-footer */
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/27rNu/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var secondary = $("#secondary-footer");
secondary.addClass("fixed");
var windowH = $('#wrapper').outerHeight(true);
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollVal < (windowH - 350 * 2)) {
        secondary.addClass("fixed");
    }
    else {
        secondary.removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

});

I also added a "wrapper" div around the whole html.